# Alternative for casting strongly-typed enum to int in C++

Tags: c++, casting, enum-class

To convert a strongly-typed enum to int we can use:

```
enum class MyEnum { a, b };
int x = static_cast<int>(MyEnum::a);
```

what if i use the following line, which is shorter:

```
int x = int(MyEnum::a);
```

**My motivation:**

I need to cast my scoped enums and my compiler (Qt creator's default i.e. mingw) generates warnings when i use old c-style casts e.g. `(int)MyEnum::a` , which I am looking to avoid. Obviously `static_cast<>()` is LONG and UGLY. So one might prefer `int(MyEnum::a)` which generates NO warnings in my compiler

**Questions:**

1- Is it just right to do it this way?

2- What are the pros and cons of the 2 approaches?

Comment: Does static_cast construct an INT?. In the second approach a new INT is constructed. It's not a cast.

Comment: `int(MyEnum::a);` is identical to `(int)MyEnum::a;` ie a c-style cast that if it can't do anything safe will use `reinterpret_cast` to get the job done probably resulting in Undefined Behaviour.  `static_cast` will report an error and potentially save you from a typing (or other) mistake.

Comment: You could also add a converter helper, `inline int to_int(MyEnum x) noexcept { return static_cast<int>(x); }`

Comment: @alirakiyan it is a cast see (2) here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: Thanks to all specifically @RichardCritten. I wanted to avoid the LONG and UGLY look of `static_cast<>()` but it seems this is by design and maybe i would be better off if I actually used static_cast ??? 
**Any comments???**
I came to this conclusion after reading this [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50442/c-style-casts-or-c-style-casts).

Comment: @Eljay Or you can define a unary `+` operator: `int operator +(MyEnum arg) { return static_cast<int>(arg); }`. Then, if you're using it a lot, it's a lot less typing to just do stuff like: `int i = +MyEnum::b;`.

Comment: This [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used/332086#332086) mentions that `(Type)...` and `Type(...)` are both old c-style casts. BUT my compiler does not generatre warnings for the latter!!!
Any way it looks i should avoid `int(MyEnum::a)`

Comment: @RichardCritten It's true that `T(expr)` is the same as `(T)expr` - but the "dangerous" cases of these apply to pointer and reference casts; if `T` is not a pointer or reference type, it will always act exactly like `static_cast`. So in my own coding style I'm fine with `T(expr)` as long as `T` is a keyword or possibly-qualified identifier, is not type-dependent, and is not an alias for a pointer or reference type. Calls for extra care inside a template, though.

Comment: @AdrianMole • I use — *and really like* — the unary `+` as a converter in my own code.  Many of the C++ devs I work with dislike that usage (although not as much as they dislike the use of `auto`), and declare it **forbidden** in the team's C++ coding guidelines.  Alas.  :-(